# Flashing Lineage OS 14.1 Nexus 5 hammerhead

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, boot, rom, lineageos

I am flashing my Lineage OS 14.1 on my Nexus 5 (hammerhead). It went without error, and I am now booting. However, the curved line with a circle cycling from right to left has been looping for >10 minutes. Is it still "working"? Has it frozen? Should I do a hard reset (hold power and volume down)?

Thanks.

Comment: Too much info missing. What's the base before you flashed anything? TWRP version? Have you clean wiped before flashing?

Comment: If it is a clean flash, it takes more time. Also, you haven't told anything that Andy Yan mentioned.

Comment: @AndyYan TWRP verision 2.8.7.1.. it is a clean flash, all processes wiped.. I repeated it last night and let it cycle over night, it still did not finish by the AM.. I am flashing 14.1 nightly 20170418, with Gapps arm 7.1 pico

Comment: Sounds curious, if I had the phone in my hand, I'd flash a factory image and see if it boots well. Better see if it's a problem of the phone itself, since I've been seeing a bunch of (presumably) hardware failing Nexus 5 on this site recently.